# Query task state - Celery & redis

Tags: python, redis, celery, celery-task

Okay so I have a relatively simple problem I think, and it's like I'm hitting a brick wall with it. I have a flask app, and a webpage that allows you to run a number of scripts on the server side using celery & redis(broker).

All I want to do, is when I start a task to give it a name/id (task will be portrayed as a button on the client side) i.e.

```
@app.route('/start_upgrade/<task_name>')
def start_upgrade(task_name):
    example_task.delay(1, 2, task_name=task_name)
```

Then after the task has kicked off I want to see if the task is running/waiting/finished in a seperate request, preferably like;

```
@app.route('/check_upgrade_status/<task_name>')
def get_task_status(task_name):
    task = celery.get_task_by_name(task_name)  
    task_state = task.state
    return task_state # pseudocode
```

But I can't find anything like that in the docs. I am very new to celery though just FYI so assume I know nothing. Also just to be extra obvious, I need to be able to query the task state from python, no CLI commands please.

Any alternative methods of achieving my goal of querying the queue are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up figuring out a solution for my question from arthur's post.

In conjunction with redis I created these functions

```
import redis
from celery.result import AsyncResult

redis_cache = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

def check_task_status(task_name):
    task_id = redis_cache.get(task_name)
    return AsyncResult(task_id).status

def start_task(task, task_name, *args, **kwargs):
    response = task.delay(*args, **kwargs)
    redis_cache.set(task_name, response.id)
```

Which allows me to define specific names to tasks. Note I haven't actually tested this yet but it makes sense so.

Example usage;

```
start_task(example_task, "example_name", 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start a task with `delay` or `apply_async` an object `AsyncResult`is created and contains the id of the task. To get it you just have to store it in a variable.

For example

```
@app.route('/start_upgrade/<task_name>')
def start_upgrade(task_name):
    res = example_task.delay(1, 2, task_name=task_name)
    print res.id
```

You can store this id and maybe associate it with something else in a database (or just print it like I did in the example).

Then you can check the status of your task in a python console with :

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
AsyncResult(your_task_id).status
```

Take a look at the result documentation you should get what you need there : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html

Comment: [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=AsyncResult#celery.app.task.Task.AsyncResult) is on the updated celery docs located at https://docs.celeryq.dev/.